# If your site has been flagged, "this site may harm your computer" how long before Google takes action

Tags: google, seo, malware

If your site has "this site may harm your computer" in the search results how long can you be in that situation before Google takes action. When they do take action does anyone know what that action is? I assume it results ultimately in delisting but I can't find anything specific.

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=163633 See the very bottom for requesting a malware review.

Comment: It's not my site.. I just got to wondering what eventually happens to those sites if corrective action isn't taken.

Answer (score 2):

The site, with the warning, seems to stay in the google rankings. However, if someone clicks on that listing, they would be taken to a google warning page telling them to go no further. To get to the site you actually have to copy and past the address into your browser's location bar. This would seriously reduce the amount of traffic you get from google.

Comment: If you google it, there are numerous instances where people say it will be delisted, so it seems at some point they take action.

Comment: I know many people say so but there are many SEO fables. I have seen sites with this notice remain in the search results of years with no change. The only comments I can find that actually come form google employees (rather than guesses) say that google doesn't remove the sites but rather tries to contact the webmaster by email, google webmasters and through that warning message. See: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=550dcdd4beaa740f&hl=en

Comment: In addition, sites blocked by this warning will also be blocked in Chrome and Firefox. If people see links that are not working, they will remove the link from their site. So with time PR is going to drop which will affect search rank.

Comment: You might be right. I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if any other answers are posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you request a review through Google Webmaster Tools you should see a delisting in about 24 hours providing your site is verified to now be clean.

Repeat instances don't seem to affect this timescale.

We've had a situation in the past where a shared server host was hacked and the sites were continually reinfected. One one particular site I requested reviews several times, each time it was delisted within a few hours, but no more than a day.

This was 4 or 5 years ago though, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once. I installed a plugin to a wordpress website that contained a link to a website. That website was flagged and so was mine. I corrected the problem and notified them through Google webmaster tools.

I suppose that if someone cannot correct the problem, then his website will be lost from SERPs eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I had a website running WordPress which had a vulnerable plugin and was injected with some rogue javascript in the index.php file. Nothing malicious, but Google picked it up as a harmful site. I removed the js from the index, removed that plugin and updated everything on the site. Google naturally updated their index to remove the warning. If your site doesn't have much traffic you may submit it from webmaster tools for them to review.